# Finding the magnitude of a vector knowing its unit vector and its relationship with another vector via the vector dot product

Tags: vectors

If $$\tag{1} AB \cos \theta = (\mathbf{A}\cdot \mathbf{B})$$ and values for $A$, $\mathbf{A}$, and $\mathbf{\hat B}$ are known, where $\mathbf{\hat B}$ is the unit vector of $\mathbf{B}$, how can we determine the magnitude of $\mathbf{B} \ (\equiv B)$ via Eqn(1) or some other relationship?

Comment: Hint:  if you scale a vector (positively), does that change the angle against another?

Comment: @Randall something along the line of thought? $$\cos \theta = (\mathbf{A}\cdot \mathbf{B})/AB = (\mathbf{A}\cdot \mathbf{\hat B})/A|\mathbf{\hat B}|$$

Comment: Right.  You're getting there.

Comment: @Randall Ok, subbing this result into Eqn(1), noting that $|\mathbf{\hat B}|=1$, we have $$\frac{AB(\mathbf{A}\cdot \mathbf{\hat B})}{A} = (\mathbf{A}\cdot \mathbf{B})$$ The $A$s cancel and then we have $$B(\mathbf{A}\cdot \mathbf{\hat B}) = (\mathbf{A}\cdot \mathbf{B})$$ Solving for $B$ we have $$B=\frac{(\mathbf{A}\cdot \mathbf{B})}{(\mathbf{A}\cdot \mathbf{\hat B})}$$ However, we don't know $\mathbf{B}$, so this line of thought I'm going is wrong. Hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear if you are taking equation (1) as a general identity, or if you are assuming you know the actual value of the dot product.  I'll assume throughout that neither $\mathbf{A}$ nor $\mathbf{B}$ are the zero vector.

If you know the value of the dot product *and it is not zero*, you can find $|\mathbf{B}|$ easily.  The angle $\theta$ is known since you know $\hat{\mathbf{A}}$ and $\hat{\mathbf{B}}$.  We have that $\hat{\mathbf{A}} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{B}} = \cos \theta$ because the angle doesn't change when you scale by a positive scalar:  the $\theta$ here must be the same $\theta$ in equation (1).  Since $\theta$, the dot product, and $|\mathbf{A}|$ are known,
$$
|\mathbf{B}| = \frac{\mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{B}}{|\mathbf{A}| \cos \theta}.
$$
Division by $\cos \theta$ is fine since $\theta$ cannot be $\pi/2$.

If you know the value of the dot product and it *is* zero, then you cannot determine the length of $\mathbf{B}$.  Here $\mathbf{B}$ is perpendicular to $\mathbf{A}$, and infinitely many vectors (of infinitely many different lengths) do that.

Without knowing the value of the dot product in (1), you cannot determine the value of $|\mathbf{B}|$.  You say that $\hat{\mathbf{B}}$ is known, but we are assuming we do *not* know the actual numerical value of $\mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{B}$ (otherwise see the previous paragraphs).  Then consider $\mathbf{B} = c\hat{\mathbf{B}}$ where $c > 0$.  All such vectors satisfy your identity (1) with the correct angle $\theta$, yet they all have different lengths.